# Ember CLI Mirage: How to filter out return value?

Tags: ember.js

This is how I get all data in `config.js`:

```
this.get('/rentals', function (schema, request) {
    if (request.queryParams.value) {
        // The code should be here...
    } else {
        return schema.rentals.all();
    }

}
```

I looked at documentation, but there's no way to get filtered ones. Apparently there are commands like `all()`, `find()`, `findBy()`, `create()`, etc. But there's nothing that filters out and returns. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out: `filter` could be used with `all()`.

```
this.get('/rentals', function (schema, request) {
    if (request.queryParams.value) {
        let filteredRentals = schema.rentals.all().filter(function (i) {
            return i.attrs.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.queryParams.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
        return filteredRentals;
    }
    return schema.rentals.all();
});
```